# How to combine multiple rows based on column value(s)

Tags: sql, self-join

I'm just starting out in SQL so as always, apologizes for the notive question. I'm using SQL it for reporting purposes. I'm not trying to write data. I did not set up/nor can I modify any tables in my system.

The problem I can not seem to overcome this past weekend while googling and testing things is I have a functioning query that gives me 1 row of data across various tables per GUID [`Main_ID`]. I need to pull some data from another table that shares the same [`Main ID`] and has various but constant secondary IDs [`Attribute_ID`].

To go into more detail about the table, `Attribute_IDs` (`'Att_1'`, `'Att_2'`,...) are constant throughout the system regardless of the `Main_ID`.  And each `Attribute_ID` always correlates to the same column (`'Att_1' = archar255`, `'Att_2' = archarMAX`). There is only 1 column of data per Attribute ID. The values in the 3 rightmost columns are strings that vary.

Table - `Value_Table`

```
+-----------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| Main_ID   | Attribute_ID | archar255      | archarMAX      | LookupValue |
| GUID_ID_1 | Att_1        |                | blah blah      |             |
| GUID_ID_1 | Att_2        | 255 value test |                |             |
| GUID_ID_1 | Att_3        |                |                | LV          |
| GUID_ID_1 | Att_4        |                | MAX            |             |
| GUID_ID_1 | Att_5        |                | something else |             |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Expected Output -

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------+-------+
| Main_ID   | Att_1     | Att_2          | Att_3 | Att_4 |
| GUID_ID_1 | blah blah | 255 value test | LV    | MAX   |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+-------+-------+
```

If anyone is willing to help me out, or just simply point me in the right direction, I would be most appreciative.

I have tried using `WHERE` statements and `CASE` but it can only point to 1 of the 5 rows that actually exist.

Comment: search for pivot in sql

Comment: What is logic to get your expected output? Get `archarMAX` for `Att_1` or if `archar255` has value of  `Att_1` then get it, if not then check on `archarMAX`, if not then check on `LookupValue`? You say 'Att_1' = archar255, 'Att_2' = archarMAX but in your expected output it is opposite??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you need conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT
    vt.Main_ID,
    MAX( CASE WHEN vt.attribute_ID = 'Att_1' THEN vt.archarMAX END) Att1,
    MAX( CASE WHEN vt.attribute_ID = 'Att_2' THEN vt.archar255 END) Att2,
    MAX( CASE WHEN vt.attribute_ID = 'Att_3' THEN vt.LookupValue END) Att3,
    MAX( CASE WHEN vt.attribute_ID = 'Att_4' THEN vt.archarMAX END) Att4
FROM Value_Table vt
GROUP BY vt.Main_ID;
```

Here is [a db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50afde9055f63a034e745523ae26c9d7) with your sample data (since you did not tag your RDBMS, I chose MySQL, but this should work almost everywhere) :

```
 WITH Value_Table AS (
     SELECT 'GUID_ID_1' Main_ID, 'Att_1' Attribute_ID, null archar255, 'blah blah' archarMAX, null LookupValue
     UNION SELECT 'GUID_ID_1', 'Att_2', '255 value test', null, null
     UNION SELECT 'GUID_ID_1', 'Att_3', null, null, 'LV'
     UNION SELECT 'GUID_ID_1', 'Att_4', null, 'MAX', null
     UNION SELECT 'GUID_ID_1', 'Att_5', null, 'something else', null
 )
 SELECT
     vt.Main_ID,
     MAX( CASE WHEN vt.attribute_ID = 'Att_1' THEN vt.archarMAX END) Att1,
     MAX( CASE WHEN vt.attribute_ID = 'Att_2' THEN vt.archar255 END) Att2,
     MAX( CASE WHEN vt.attribute_ID = 'Att_3' THEN vt.LookupValue END) Att3,
     MAX( CASE WHEN vt.attribute_ID = 'Att_4' THEN vt.archarMAX END) Att4
 FROM Value_Table vt
 GROUP BY vt.Main_ID


 Main_ID   | Att1      | Att2           | Att3 | Att4
 :-------- | :-------- | :------------- | :--- | :---
 GUID_ID_1 | blah blah | 255 value test | LV   | MAX
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is why I love this community so much

Comment: Welcome @Scott !

Answer (score 0):

Here is with pivot:

```
    select main_id, max([Att_1]) as Att_1, max([Att_2]) as Att_2, max([Att_3]) as Att_3, max([Att_4]) as Att_4
from 
(
  select main_id, Attribute_ID, 
   Attribute_ID+'1' As Attribute_ID1,
   Attribute_ID+'2' As Attribute_ID2,
   archar255, archarMax, Lookupvalue
  from #yt
) as src
pivot
(
  max(archarMax)
  for Attribute_ID in ([Att_1], [Att_2], [Att_3], [Att_4])
) as piv

group by main_id
```